# Freeze Floating Image

Tags: excel, excel-2003

I have a spreadsheet which freeze panes at B9 and have data from Column A to Column Z.

I'd like to insert a image on top center of the screen. **Whenever I scroll to the right, the image will still float at top center** like a userform (but I don't want a userform)

I can only reach this state which is not my requirement:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me.Shapes("Picture 1")
        .Top = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Top
        .Left = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Left + 150
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This is probably only possible using a userform set to non modal.

Comment: Scroll using the arrow keys rather than the scroll bars.